# ActiveJdbc update join-table attribute

Tags: java, activejdbc

Good evening,
I am trying to update a join-table attribute for existing records. I have two models, one called `Records`, the other called `Shoppingcarts`. These are connected by a join table called `records_shoppingcarts`. I added a relationship attribute to the join table called `record_amount` which is supposed to hold the amount of each record in the join table.
At the moment, whenever an item is added to a shoppingcart, only one item is added. The user is then able to modify the amount of items in the shoppingcart in their checkout view. I am handling this by querying the join table `records_shoppingcarts` for entries with the corresponding record_id and updating the column `record_amount` to the new amount of records in the shoppingcart. This looks something linke that:

```
List<RecordsShoppingcarts> associations = RecordsShoppingcarts.where("shoppingcart_id = ?", s.get("id"));

            //update the number of records in the join table
            for(RecordsShoppingcarts rs : associations) {                    

                if((int)rs.getInteger("record_id") == (int)rec.getInteger("id")) {
                    rs.delete(); //cleanup
                    rs.set("record_amount", amount);
                    rs.saveIt();                        

                }
            }                
        }
```

Unfortunately though, whenever `saveIt()` gets called; the entry isn't updated in the database but a new entry is created with the same `shoppingcart_id`,  `recordId` and the updated amount. I am probably missing something here, since I can't imagine manually updating join tables is intended. Unfortunately though, I couldn't find anything on updating relationship attributes in join tables. Is this even provided by ActiveJdbc?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Best wishes, derelektrischemoench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework is working exactly as expected. You need to familiarize yourself with how it decides to create a new record or update an existing one by reading this page: http://javalite.io/surrogate_primary_keys

Basically, you are deleting a record by:

```
 rs.delete();
```

so, next time you do:

```
rs.saveIt();
```

it creates a new record. Simply remove the `rs.delete();` and you will be fine.

Comment: Hi ipolevoy, I found the culprit. I didn't read the manual carefully enough, my database design had a bug. I forgot to declare an id column on the share table. Fixed that, update works. Which makes sense because how else should the framework find the correct entry in the m:n table. Thanks  for having the patience to deal with my ignorance :). I guess I owe you some beers. Keep up the good work, best wishes.